# How to compare 1st character of a string to a specific character in VBScript?

Tags: string, vbscript, char

I have a string. I need to compare 1<sup>st</sup> character of the string to a specific character. Below is the C# code.

```C#
String URL = "www.vulnuryrweb.com";

bool isValid = URL[0] == '/'
               && URL[1] != '/' 
               && URL[1] != '\\';
```

What will be VB-Script equivalent of above code?

Answer (score 1):

```
URL = "www.vulnuryrweb.com"

char1 = Left(URL, 1)
char2 = Mid(URL, 2, 1)

isValid = ( char1 = "/" And char2 <> "/" And char2 <> "\" )

MsgBox isValid
```

---

**Update**: It can be simplified with the [`Like` operator](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/language/reference/user-interface-help/like-operator) :

```
URL = "www.vulnuryrweb.com"

isValid = URL Like "/[/\]*"

Debug.Print isValid
```

`[/\]` checks if the second character is `/` or `\`, and `*` matches 0 or more characters.

Comment: Judging from the highlighting, this does not seem to be valid.

Comment: @Laurel more like the StackOverflow code highlighting had problem with the \ at the end. I tried it before posting and it works.

Answer (score 0):

According to http://www.w3schools.com/asp/func_mid.asp you will need to do

```
URL = "www.vulnuryrweb.com";
firstLetter = Mid(URL,1,1)
```

which will return `w` in this case

Answer (score 0):

use the Mid function to get the first n chars of a string, then compare this to the results you want to check for

```
Dim isValid
isValid = (Mid(URL, 1, 1) = "/" And Mid(URL, 2, 1) <> "/" And Mid(URL, 2, 1) <> "\")
```

Note that Mid uses a 1 based index for characters (index `1` is the first char) whereas C# uses 0 based (`url[0]` is the first char)

Comment: In C# `"\\"` means `"\"` because \ is used for character literals like tab and new line https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa691090(v=vs.71).aspx